# How to use nested selenium selectors

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using selenium + chrome web driver to load a dynamic page:

```py
self.driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)  # not sure if I need to add this wait, so the .js loads the page?
```

Once the page is loaded, I want to get a list of all cards available on the page and then iterate through each card and get its title:

```py
cards = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.my-card')
for card in cards:
    title = card.find_element_by_css_selector('h2.title::text').get() # <-- does not work
    desc = card.find_element_by_css_selector('div.desc::text').get() # <-- does not work
    # more fields that I need within this card
```

`find_elements_by_css_selector` seems to be a `driver` method... I am not sure how to apply these selector to card (the type card is `WebElement`).

---

Sample page:

```html
<div class='my-card'>
    <h2 class='title'>title 1</h2>
    <div class='desc'>desc 1</div>
</div>
<div class='my-card'>
    <h2 class='title'>title 2</h2>
    <div class='desc'>desc 2</div>
</div>
<div class='my-card'>
    <h2 class='title'>title 3</h2>
    <div class='desc'>desc 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of cards or the html of a card please. That would help.

Comment: You need a webdriver wait after driver.get to allow for page load.

Comment: @arundeepchohan: it's not just the title... there are multiple fields within the card that I need... that's why I am iterating the card... is there no way to use a css selector on the card element?

Comment: They are ways to go down a card element but we need the html element layout in order to do so.

Comment: @arundeepchohan: I have added a sample html... as I mentioned in the question, there are more fields... I am just showing title and description

Comment: That was a typo... I removed it

Comment: Currently what errors do you come up with once you add the wait and print(title.text)?

Comment: What you have there already actually works for me on the example you gave... `card.find_element_by_css_selector('h2.title')` returns the h2 element...

Comment: @sytech: thanks a lot... I updated the question... I have `title = card.find_element_by_css_selector('h2.title::text').get()` which I believe is the incorrect syntax (I mistakenly used the Scrapy syntax)... I want to get the text inside `h2`

Comment: I don't think the pseudo class selector `::text` works here. Omit the `::text` part of the selector to get the element. Then, you can use the `.text` attribute on the webelement object to retrieve the text. e.g. `title = card.find_element_by_css_selector('h2.title").text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have works as-is. Using your given example HTML:

```
In [19]: for card in cards:
    ...:     title_elem = card.find_element_by_css_selector('h2.title')
    ...:     print(title_elem.text)
    ...:
title 1
title 2
title 3

In [20]: card
Out[20]: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="534c4be3a233a0aa963f541550ac7861", element="b56dcaf3-9b38-4e4c-aae8-99005ac9840b")>
```

So. Your expectation of using nested selenium selectors is correct. Some other assumption must be throwing you off.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I updated the question.. I guess the problem was using the Scrapy syntax for getting the text inside h2 element... do you know how can I get the inner html of `h2`?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini in the example above you could do `title_elem.get_attribute('innerHTML')` -- [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium)

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the two into one query (CSS) selector like so by using the combinator child or descendent selector.

If the h2 element is a child *and* a descendent of the card element:

```py
self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.my-card > h2.title')
```

If the h2 element is only a descendent of the card element:

```py
self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.my-card h2.title')
```

Find out more about CSS combinators [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).

Comment: This returns a list of webelements with a div class of my-card and a descendant of h2 class of title.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini perhaps something is missing from your example? The answer given here returns a list of all three `h2` elements containing the title. Or is there something else missing from this answer?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Yeah, it returns a `list[WebElement]`, where each of the elements in the list is the title of a card.